# Create folder outside the container in the host machine

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose

I want to change the folder to which the config-server downloads files from git.

when I do it locally in windows, it works perfectly fine, and I can find the created folder.

but when I deploy the config-server to docker, I can't find the folder in the path I chose

this is my properties config

```
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: "https://bitbucket.org/xxx/remote-config.git"
          username: "xxx"
          password: "xxx"
          basedir: "${CONFIG_LOCAL_REPO_DIR}"
          default-label: "master"
          clone-on-start: true
          force-pull: true
```

and this is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  config-server:
    image: "config-server:1.0"
    build: "./config-server"
    container_name: "config_server"
    restart: "always"
    networks:
      - "network"
    volumes:
      - "myvolume"
    depends_on:
      - "rabbitmq"
    environment:
      CONFIG_LOCAL_REPO_DIR: "myvolume:/home/debian/backend-app/local-repo"


volumes:
  myvolume:

networks:
  network:
```

how can I solve this to create in my machine the folder I have chosen?

Comment: what do you mean by you can find? From the looks of it your data will be in a managed volume. If you want it on the host, use a bind mount. Technically it's with a managed volume on the host too, but it's not really meant to be used for this purpose.

Comment: thank you @TheFool for your reply. I have a "/home/debian/backend-app" folder. in this folder I put my services, and my docker-compose file. I want the config-server to create the "local-repo" in the same folder ("/home/debian/backend-app")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the data to easily accessible on the host system, i.e. in the same dir as the compose file, use a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

```yaml
services:
  config-server:
    volumes:
      - ./local-repo:/myrepo
    environment:
      CONFIG_LOCAL_REPO_DIR: /myrepo
```

Note, this is not referencing a volume from the `volumes:` key in the YAML file, but a path on the host system. In this case, relative to the compose file.

Comment: that's what i m looking for, thank you